# Docker container with filesystem encryption?

Tags: docker

I have not tried Docker containers yet but I'm evaluating it for the needs I have. For instance I'd like to use a basic file system to read/write some data during runtime. I also want some kind of encryption for this. I can encrypt the bytes myself but perhaps standard file system encryption is better/faster? The question is, does Docker containers have support for any encrypted file systems? (I will host this container on Linux and using .net core as app-framework.)

Comment: Why not use FDE on the docker host?

Comment: I don't have access to the host, only what docker exposes

Comment: If you don't have access to the host, I think that would be very difficult find a solution other than encrypt at application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use volumes for that.  The volume must reside on a filesystem encrypted with cryptsetup (dm-crypt).  This filesystem can be file-backed.

Some pointers:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4